# Generics casting an unknown type to another

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, generics

I'm rewording my question to be more specific and target the actual area of concern.

I have many different classes which are my entities, I do not what is in that class. When I want to upgrade the entities to new ones, I want to transfer the properties to the new ones which are called the same (and as I have found out, they are case insensitive).

My Problem is simple, but probably requires a complex answer.

When I come across a type which is different to the upgraded one I need to cast the old one to the new one. Both types are unknown, because thats the point. I can pass through any two classes I want and it will transfer the properties fine.

So if I had two classes:

```
public class OldEntity
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int SomeProperty {get;set;}
}

public class NewEntity
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string SomeProperty {get;set;}
}
```

So I need to find out what the old type of `SomeProperty`, then cast it to the new type of `SomeProperty`.

What I thought I could do, and I hope there is a more generic way of doing it:

```
switch (typeof(SomeProperty.Value.GetType())
{
    case typeof(Int):
        return Int.Parse(OldSomeProperty.Value);
}
```

Obviously that is very raw code but you get the gist.

Please can someone give me a more generic way of doing that, one more thing is I have AutoMapper downloaded, it isn't commented so if anyone could tell me where and how it does it that would be a good answer as well.

So I've tried to simple work around, not very generic:

```
public static object ConvertSourceObjectDestinationObject(object source, object destination)
{
    // get the string representation of the source object
    var strRepresentation = source.ToString();
    // find out the destinations type
    var originalCode = AssemblyCode(destination.GetType().Assembly.ToString());

    // search for a match then convert the source object to the new destination objects type
    switch (originalCode)
    {
        case 0:
            return strRepresentation;
        case 1:
            return int.Parse(strRepresentation);
        case 2:
            return decimal.Parse(strRepresentation);
        case 3:
            return DateTime.Parse(strRepresentation);
        case 4:
            return byte.Parse(strRepresentation);
        case 5:
            return float.Parse(strRepresentation);
        case 6:
            return Guid.Parse(strRepresentation);
        default:
            return strRepresentation;
    }
}

public static int AssemblyCode(string assemblyString)
{
    if (assemblyString.Equals(typeof(string).Assembly.ToString()))
        return 0;

    if (assemblyString.Equals(typeof(int).Assembly.ToString()))
        return 1;

    if (assemblyString.Equals(typeof(decimal).Assembly.ToString()))
        return 2;

    if (assemblyString.Equals(typeof(DateTime).Assembly.ToString()))
        return 3;

    if (assemblyString.Equals(typeof(byte).Assembly.ToString()))
        return 4;

    if (assemblyString.Equals(typeof(float).Assembly.ToString()))
        return 5;

    if (assemblyString.Equals(typeof(Guid).Assembly.ToString()))
        return 6;

    return -1;
}
```

I have done a new one which does a TryParse instead of a Parse to make it more safe, but you get the gist. Its not elegant I know, but if someone could fill me in with how to cast unknown objects to other unknown objects properly that would be great.

Comment: I don't understand your question. `GetValue` and `SetValue` operate on `object`s so why do you need to cast? It would probably help if instead of using an abstract example with `x` and `y` you showed specific line that causes problems in your method.

Comment: That method is where it's going wrong. I pass just the object, then it throughs an error about casting!

Comment: I'm sorry for the patronising tone. I checked your profile and you are absolutely correct.

Comment: It would help if you posted the exact exception.

Comment: I can't at the moment, but you can try it, just use this method, and create some classes which have the same properties but using different types.

Comment: @No1_Melman Are you trying to create a generic CRUD btw?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what "generics" means in the programming world. It has nothing to do with being able to use just any type. You may want to have a look at [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic system needs some help knowing what type the generics are at times.  This is taken care of with a type constraint ([ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/d5x73970%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), which may help you with your example.

If you know the generic type you are wanting to cast is always of some base class, use the `where T:<base class name>` constraint.

If the cast exception is due to it not recognizing an implicit cast between types that are not inherited, reflection may be you only option.

Answer (score 0):

You use the generic constraint new

```
 public static void SetEntityValue<TEntity>(ref TEntity entityToTransform, PropertyHelper entityProperty) where TEntity: new
```

which will allow you to do:

```
TEntity ent = new TEntity()
```

OR (and I think this is what you want)

using the same thing (generic constraints) you can tell the method what the generic parameter types are/derive from.

```
public static void SetEntityValue<TEntity>(ref TEntity entityToTransform, PropertyHelper entityProperty) where TEntity: x
```

which basically means you can tell the compiler what the generic types must be (which means your casts in the method will make sense and compile

If you have NO idea what the type will be then you may be into using reflection on the object...

Comment: I'm not trying to instantiate the object, I want to cast its properties values to another objects properties values!

Comment: I guess I will be into using reflection then.

Comment: Reading your other comments you can make the generic method accept only types that derive from a specific interface (that has all the property accessors needed and shared) and add the generic constraint of that interface @No1_Melman